# What does the bar symbol over a scalar means in the context of complex vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

In chapter 5.3 in "Elementary Linear Algebra" titled "Complex vector spaces" I came across a weird notation that I don't understand and can't find an example or explanation anywhere.

In one of the theorems it says:

*If **u** is a vector and if k is a scalar, then*:
$$\overline{ku} = \overline{k}\overline{u}$$

Now I understand what a conjugate of a complex number and vector is and that a real number(scalar) is also complex.
But I'm not sure I understand the notation...

$$ \overline{ku} = \overline{(ka_1 + kb_1i, ka_2 + kb_2i, \dots , ka_n + kb_ni)} = (ka_1 - kb_1i, ka_2 - kb_2i, \dots , ka_n - kb_ni) $$

Right? So my conclusion from this is to think of $\overline{k}$ as meaning "multiply real part by $k$ and multiply complex part by $k$ as well but also change the sign:
$\overline{k}\overline{u} = ka - kbi$ ?

It does line up with another theorem presented later which is $u*kv = \overline{k}(u*v)$.

But did I get it correctly? It feels a bit odd...

Comment: if you have a complex vector space, then the set of scalars is the field of complex numbers. So in general, $k= x+iy$ (with real $x,y$).

Comment: Oh that's a good point. So if that's the case then I understand :)